How to account for multiple measurements of 2 different tissues of a same tree/branch?
I am doing DNA extractions and DNA quality assesment on those results, based on spectrometry (260/280nm values). So i want to compare or see if there is differences between the DNA extracted from leaves v/s buds from the same tree, with 15 individuals.
I think that t-test is one of the approaches that i can use, but i'm struggling choosing between paired and independent t-test. I could be wrong in thinking that t-test is the approach, so i appreciate any suggestions

It will help to describe the data you collect in more detail. How many data points (extractions & quality assessments) do you from each tree?

Welcome to Cross Validated! Because your group A (leaves) and group B (buds) measurements are being collected from the same trees, a paired test (either paired t-test or Wilcoxon signed rank test) would be best to use.
You should also descriptively look at your data using visualizations such as a histogram, box plot, etc. to get an idea of the distribution of your outcome variable. This will help inform which test to use.
